# Is there a way to edit point colours in the R package ggphylomorpho?

Tags: r, phylogeny

I'm using ggphylomorpho to make a phylomorphospace plot, but the point colours on the resulting plot are not what I need. I need to be able to specify what colour I want for each individual point.

I've looked through all the package arguments and don't see any options for colour adjustment, but I'm very new to R (and coding in general) and might be missing something. Is there any way to edit point colours on a plot made using ggphylomorpho? I like the functionality and look of the plot otherwise, so would love to be able to make this one last adjustment.

Comment: Welcome to SO, acdos! Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (please be explicit about non-base packages), sample representative data (perhaps via `dput(head(x))` or building data programmatically (e.g., `data.frame(...)`), possibly stochastically), perhaps actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: Additionally, the Stack tag-recommendation system is imperfect. I removed the [tag:devtools] tag, as this does not appear to have anything to do with the R package (even if you may have used it to install the `ggphylomorpho` package.

Comment: If your phylomorphoplot has, say, groups "group 1" and "group 2", something like this should work: `ggphylomorpho(...) + scale_color_manual(values = c("group 1" = "green", "group 2" = "blue"))`. Admittedly that's hard to find out from the documentation without familiarity with `ggplot` plots.